# Correct way to link to views (to solve multi-domain problem)

Tags: views, navigation, domain-access

I have one site (same codebase, same database) that uses two different domains to display two different themes, depending on the content. (This is achieved via the *Domain Access* module.)

I need to be able to link from one domain to a view on another domain without manually inserting the absolute URL, but I'm not sure how (or even if it's possible).*

I can use `l()` to link to nodes without any problems. For example, if I'm on **first-domain.com** and I want to link to **second-domain.com/news-story**, I would do the following:

`<?php print l('News Story', 'node/2213'); ?>`

I don't know exactly how it works, but it realises that the news story isn't available on the first domain and automatically creates the absolute link to the second domain.

Creating a link to a view doesn't seem to be so easy. I've made sure the view's *Access restrictions* is set to *Domains* (and that only the one domain is selected) but the `l()` function doesn't seem to look this up.

For example, if I'm on **first-domain.com** and want to link to a list of all the news stories (which is created by a view) on **second-domain.com**, doing this:

`<?php print l('Latest News Stories', 'news-stories'); ?>`

Results in a link like this:

`first-domain.com/news-stories`

When I really want: `second-domain.com/news-stories`

Is there any way to solve this? Even if I could look up both domains that have been set via the *Domain Access* module would work, but I don't know how to do that either. (I've also thought about using Path Redirect, which is better than nothing, but not quite what I'm looking for.)

* Obviously it's possible to put in an absolute URL, but this is far from ideal as the site is currently being developed locally and will eventually be moved to a staging site, and then moved again to production once ready. Remembering to change the absolute links every time would be annoying at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you obviously are capable of PHP, the best way I can think of is to write a custom wrapper for `l()`, something like:

```
function ml($text, $path, int $domain = NULL, array $options = array()) {
  switch ($domain) {
    case 1:
      return l($text, 'http://first-domain.com/'.$path, $options);
      break;
    case 2:
      return l($text, 'http://second-domain.com/'.$path, $options);
      break;
    default:
      return l($text, $path, $options);
      break;
  }
}
```

That way, the absolute domains only have to be changed in this one central place with each staging step (domains may even be stored in settings.php).

Comment: Thank you so much--you've just saved me a TON of time! 
(Just a minor change: PHP complained about `$domain = 0`, so I changed it to `$domain = NULL`.)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, I changed the $domain parameter to default to NULL.